# select where like with an array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$tag = 'sky';
```

select rows where `tags` contains `$tag`:

```
$sql = "select * from images where tags like '%" . $tag . "%' order by date desc";
```

What if I have an array of tags:

```
$tags = array('sky', 'earth', 'sun'); // max 3

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $sql = "select * from images where tags like '%" . $tag . "%' order by date desc";
}
```

Is this the right way, especially regarding performances.

The table `images` has about 20.000 rows.

Comment: This is a lot easier with a proper relational structure rather than a singular field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp`.

```
$sql = "select * from images where tags REGEXP '" . implode('|', $tags) . "'  order by date desc";
```

Your final result will be:

```
select * from images where tags REGEXP 'sky|earth|sun' order by date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple tags to your query using `OR` in your query

```
$sql = "select * from images where tags like '%" . $tag[0] . "%' OR tags like '%" . $tag[1] . "%' OR tags like '%" . $tag[2] . "%' order by date desc";
```

You don't need to use `foreach` to run query

**UPDATE 1**

```
$comma_separated = "('" . implode("','", $tags) . "')";
$sql = "select * from images where tags IN ".$comma_separated;
```

**Most Efficient Way**

A [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) might be more efficient, you have to benchmark it by your self

```
$sql = "select * from images where tags REGEXP '" . implode('|', $tags) . "'  order by date desc";
```

Comment: but array `tags` could have 1 or 2 or 3 elements?

Comment: You can use `implode` for this + you can also use `IN` instead of `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation, you don't have to know the array size.

```
$tags = array('one', 'two');
$sql = "select * from images where tags like '%" . implode("%' OR tags like '%",$tags) . "%' order by date desc";
```